# Vi keys in Xpdf?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf

The Xpdf man page says that [it can be customized](http://manned.org/xpdf.1) to work with Vi style keybindings:

```
Previous  versions  of  xpdf  included  a  "viKeys" X resource.  It is no
longer available, but the following bindings are equivalent:

   bind h any scrollLeft(16)
   bind l any scrollRight(16)
   bind k any scrollUp(16)
   bind j any scrollDown(16)
```

But nothing happens after I add those lines to `~/.xpdfrc`.  What could be going on?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you restart xpdf after saving ~/.xpdfrc. Also, if not already, could you check xpdf logs to see if there were any messages indicating it read .xpdfrc.

Comment: IIRC, Xpdf is not maintained any more. If you are looking for a light-weight PDF viewer, you might want to have a look at [`zathura`](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/).

Comment: @peterph: Xpdf 3.04 was released 2014-may-28. http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

Comment: OK, but the previous release was about 3 and half years ago. Which is not a sign of a very live product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had version 3.03 installed. At least here `.xpdfrc` was opened and read, according to `strace`, but no settings had any effect. Downloaded and tested [version 3.04](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) and here bindings work fine.

Quick to do:

```
wget ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdf-3.04.tar.gz
tar xzvf xpdf-3.04.tar.gz
cd xpdf-3.04
```

Install FreeType 2 dev and Motif dev. For debian and the like something like:

```
apt-get install libmotif-dev libfreetype6-dev libfreetype6
```

Configure and make:

```
# Read INSTALL
./configure --with-freetype2-includes=/usr/include/freetype2
make
```

Test:

```
./xpdf/xpdf Path_to_some.pdf
```

Includes:

```
pdfdetach  pdfimages  pdftohtml  pdftoppm   pdftotext  
pdffonts   pdfinfo    pdftopng   pdftops    xpdf
```

---

Also had a quick look at [zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) as recommended by [@Peterph](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179757/vi-keys-in-xpdf#comment298965_179757).

Looks nice, and if you want vi(m) bindings it have a lot of default bindings that are same as in vim. E.g. `h, j, k, l, :, /, gg, G` etc. Both key-bindings and other *things* are configurable.